# How can I stop a specific Flutter widget being treated as a Semantic Node without disabling its child widgets?

Tags: flutter, accessibility

At a few points in my app, a parent widget seems to be overriding one or more descendants, which have their own Semantics, creating a sort of group semantic node. With TalkBack on Android, tapping on this node reads out each of the child nodes in turn but doesn't let them actually be selected. Its as though there's a MergeSemantics widget hidden in the tree somewhere, but I've not created any myself. Any ideas of what's going on here or how can I debug this? Is there a widget I can use to break such behaviour? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set `explicitChildNodes: true`? on the parent `semantics` widget